# Lazy-load collection with Spring.Net

Tags: c#, nhibernate, aop, spring.net

I use Spring.Net in my project for dependency injection. Now I want to use it also for lazy-loading my objects properties.

This is an example:

I use:

- CustomerDao to access database (getCustomer(idCustomer), getAddresses(idCustomer))
- Customer (Name, Surname, IList Addresses, ...)
- Address (...)

I want to configure Spring.Net to lazy-load Customer.Addresses property.

I think I've to use an Interceptor... can you point me to a simple configuration example?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that all your customer and address instances are configured in your spring configuration? This would be highly unusual. Most of the time you retrieve those type of objects (entities) from a database of some kind.

Comment: No, only CustomerDao is configured in Spring. Customer and Address are POCO entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Castle Windsor DynamicProxy implementation for creating your own proxies to lazy load your object properties. But this is no trivial task!

If you want to lazy load object properties in your DAO/DAL I'd recommend to go for a decent ORM implementation such as NHibernate.

You can find an implementation example of doing your own proxy thingy in the [this file](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/blob/master/SubSonic.Core/DataProviders/IInterceptionStrategy.cs) of the SubSonic project repository on github.

Comment: I know NHibernate, I know Castle... In this project I cannot use them! I've to use Spring.Net without an ORM.

Comment: I pointed to a proxy implementation of subsonic - that should give an idea how to achieve your own proxy implementation.

Comment: Afaik Spring.NET uses Castle Dynamic Proxy for AOP, so you might want to check if you can use it after all.